# How to put only certain elements of a div in a css box

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am taking the CSSzenGarden Challenge. I have to style the html without changing it. I am trying to place these paragraphs inside of a box, without putting the h3 inside of that box. I want h3 to be above the box containing the paragraphs.

```
    <div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
        <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
        <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
        <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>, <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr>, and the major browser creators.</p>
        <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
    </div>
```

When I use .preamble as the css selector, it puts the entire div inside of the box. When i use .preamble p as the selector, it puts each paragraph in an individual box.

How can I select all the paragraph as a group without including h3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `margin-top` with a positive and a negative value.

```
.preamble {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 20px
}
.preamble h3 {
    margin: -20px 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ez4qh3m/

As for a specific selector: You cannot do this. You can either select the whole container `.preamble` or single elements `.preamble p`, `.preamble h3` but you cannot select a container while excluding its children.

Comment: Works. Excellent. Was toying with this idea before, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Wait, I need to get rid of that empty space at the top of the box. Is there a way to offset that?

Comment: See the edit above. I forgot to offset the bottom margin as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `p` elements within your `div.preamble` element like this:

```
div.preamble > p {
    /* some nice styling goes here */
}
```

This selects all the **direct** children of the `div.preable` element that are paragraph elements.

You can also select all children (so not necessarily direct) of a certain type like this:

```
div.preamble * {
    /* even more nice styling goes here */
}
```

You can replace the asterisk with any element you like, or leave it there and select all childeren of `div.preamble`. I hope this clears things up, good luck!

---

I just noticed I didn't answer your question completely. You can't 'make a box' around the paragraphs because a box doesn't really mean anything, except maybe wrapping your paragraphs inside an actual element, like a `div`. You can however gave all the paragraphs the same background colour:

```
div.preamble > p {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or put a border around them:

```
/* put a border around all paragraphs and remove their margin */
div.preamble > p {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

/* remove the bottom margin of the first and second paragraph 
 * (remember that they are preceded by a heading element, so the 
 * first paragraph is the second child) */
div.preamble > p:nth-child(2), div.preamble > p:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* remove the top margin of the second and third paragraph */
div.preamble > p:nth-child(3), div.preamble > p:nth-child(4) {
    border-top: none;
}
```

I think this is as close as you can get to making a box of you paragraphs. Again, good luck.

Comment: This also puts each paragraph into it's own box.

Answer (score 0):

this answer as extra possibility since you are done.

The table-layout here can be usefull and will keep everything in the regular flow of the document: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jwbvm)**

Basic CSS :

```
.preamble {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
  background:/* whatever */;
  border:double; /* whatever, optionnal */
}
.preamble h3 {
  display:table-caption;
  background:/* whatever */;
  text-align:center;/* whatever, optionnal */
  margin:1em 0;/* whatever, optionnal */
}
```

---

```
<edit data-why="any feed back ?"/>
```

[image: get this h3 outside]